# adding response header to Jetty config file

Tags: jetty

I am trying to add a response header to the Jetty configuration the following command,

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Ok so this Jetty webserver is the base on which Geoserver is running. I asked this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25968/adding-access-control-allow-origin-to-jetty-in-geoserver) in the GIS forum but no one was able to answer it so I felt I might get the answer here. I wish to add this response to the header to remove the error

```
Unable to load XMLHttpRequest
```

I wish to know that under which tags should I wrap this response header and where in the file should I save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference is to add headers in a proxying web server. If you have Apache HTTP infront of your Jetty instance then use the `Header` directive.

In answer to the question, to perform this purely in Jetty see [setting-http-headers-with-jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009631/setting-http-headers-with-jetty)